# Exception In distinct values from Collection - CurrentBSONType is UNDEFINED

Tags: java, mongodb, database, nosql

I am getting "CurrentBSONType is UNDEFINED" exception while making a db call that fetches distinct records from a Mongo collection.

Our Mongo collection looks like this :

```
    {
    "_id": ObjectId("5672be450d71c945772b8393"),
    "productId": "P-moac-49678195574",
    "title": "Flip Cover Lenovo",
    "description": "Cosmos Flip Cover  ",
    "currency": "INR",
    "productURL": "",
    "sellingPrice": 150,
    "subcategories": [{
        "name": "Mobile Accessories",
        "parent": {
            "name": "Mobile Accessories"
        }
    }],
    "imageURLs": [{
        "imageurl": "",
        "height": 0,
        "width": 0
    }],
    "attributes": [{
        "key": "model",
        "value": "Flip Cover"
    }],
    "created": ISODate("2015-12-17T13:53:09.757Z"),
    "modified": ISODate("2015-12-17T13:53:09.757Z"),
    "merchant": "IB",
    "brand": "Cosmos",
    "reviews": null
}
```

And java code to get **distinct** values of subcategories :

```
    public Map<String, SubCategory> getSubCategories() throws StatementCreationException, SQLException {
        MongoCollection<Document> productsCollection = connectionFactory.getMongoCollection("products");
        DistinctIterable<Document> result = productsCollection.distinct("subcategories", Document.class);
        Map<String, SubCategory> subcategories = new LinkedHashMap<String, SubCategory>();
        for (Iterator<Document> iterator = result.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Document subCatDoc = iterator.next();
            String subCatName = subCatDoc.getString("name");
            if (subCatName == null || subCatName.trim().isEmpty()) {
                continue;
            }
            SubCategory subCat = new SubCategoryImpl();
            subCat.setName(subCatName);
            Document categoryDoc = (Document)subCatDoc.get("parent");
            if (categoryDoc != null) {
                Category category = new CategoryImpl();
                category.setName(categoryDoc.getString("name"));
                subCat.setCategory(category);
            }
            subcategories.put(subCatName, subCat);
        }
        return subcategories;
    }
```

MongoDb throws following exception when the above method is invoked :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: readStartDocument can only be called when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT, not when CurrentBSONType is UNDEFINED.
```

Full stack trace :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: readStartDocument can only be called when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT, not when CurrentBSONType is UNDEFINED.
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.verifyBSONType(AbstractBsonReader.java:655)
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.checkPreconditions(AbstractBsonReader.java:687)
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.readStartDocument(AbstractBsonReader.java:421)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.decode(DocumentCodec.java:138)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.decode(DocumentCodec.java:45)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandResultArrayCodec.decode(CommandResultArrayCodec.java:48)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandResultDocumentCodec.readValue(CommandResultDocumentCodec.java:53)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:81)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:40)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandProtocol.execute(CommandProtocol.java:122)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:159)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:260)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:147)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:166)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:157)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:82)
    at com.mongodb.operation.DistinctOperation$1.call(DistinctOperation.java:129)
    at com.mongodb.operation.DistinctOperation$1.call(DistinctOperation.java:126)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:196)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:169)
    at com.mongodb.operation.DistinctOperation.execute(DistinctOperation.java:126)
    at com.mongodb.operation.DistinctOperation.execute(DistinctOperation.java:56)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:760)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:747)
    at com.mongodb.OperationIterable.iterator(OperationIterable.java:47)
    at com.mongodb.DistinctIterableImpl.iterator(DistinctIterableImpl.java:80)
    at com.mr10q.parser.dao.service.mongo.impl.MongoDBPersistentServiceImpl.getSubCategories(MongoDBPersistentServiceImpl.java:713)
```

Comment: Can you paste the complete error stack trace?

Comment: Posted the complete stack trace as well

Comment: Document categoryDoc = (Document)subCatDoc.get("parent"); looks suspicious to me. subCatDoc is already a document and not sure why you are casting to Document?

Comment: The exception is in  result.iterator() which is line 713 as mentioned in the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only Problem is that "subcategories" is an Array of Documents.

Hence passing **Document[].class** as resultClass parameter of the distinct call would do what you want.

E.g.:

```
DistinctIterable<Document[]> result = productsCollection.distinct("subcategories", Document[].class);
```